# Spring application is not shutting down

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, shutdown, debezium

I faced with puzzling problem. I'm using debezium engine in my project, and if debezium connector can't started, I'd like to do gracefull shutdown for my app. So I added `SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext,()->1);`
in ConnectorCallback when connector is stopped.

After all that code executed, I'm getting the main problem. Application is not shutting down. I did the thread dump, but I didn't see the problem.

```
    Full thread dump

"RMI Scheduler(0)@2135" daemon prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-9-thread-1@13887" prio=5 tid=0x89 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-1@13895" prio=5 tid=0x91 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-2@13896" prio=5 tid=0x92 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-3@13897" prio=5 tid=0x93 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-4@13898" prio=5 tid=0x94 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-5@13899" prio=5 tid=0x95 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-6@13900" prio=5 tid=0x96 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-7@13901" prio=5 tid=0x97 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-10-thread-8@13902" prio=5 tid=0x98 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"pool-11-thread-1@13944" prio=5 tid=0xa7 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"Common-Cleaner@1109" daemon prio=8 tid=0xb nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
      at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:148)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
      at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:134)

"RMI TCP Accept-0@1696" daemon prio=5 tid=0x10 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:-1)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:551)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:519)
      at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:394)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:366)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.0.101@1928" daemon prio=5 tid=0x12 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
      - locked <0x36af> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:544)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$83.488161462.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"RMI TCP Connection(2)-192.168.0.101@14040" daemon prio=5 tid=0xa9 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
      - locked <0x443c> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:544)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$83.488161462.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.0.101@17109" daemon prio=5 tid=0xb0 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
      - locked <0x443d> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:544)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$83.488161462.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"Reference Handler@13990" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Reference.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:241)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:213)

"Finalizer@13991" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:170)

"Signal Dispatcher@13992" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener@1731" daemon prio=9 tid=0x11 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"DestroyJavaVM@14434" prio=5 tid=0xaa nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Please give me some advice, that can help me

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the error log maybe it is stream data from the show link and that stream is not closed this might be the issue of not closing of spring boot

When we stream data serialize of bytes change to object till it wait for object creation.

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)


"Common-Cleaner@1109" daemon prio=8 tid=0xb nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
```

The share Code snippet so that problem is more clear to answer

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea or an inspiration!

I don't know debezium, but I would write a kind of service which can check the if debezium is running or can check the database connection itself. This service should be called at ApplicationReadyEvent and should throw a RuntimeException, which triggers a gracefull shutdown.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // optional catch the Exception to exit with a defined code
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(YourApp.class, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(11);
        } 
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> createApplicationReadyListener(YourTestService test) {
        return e -> {
            if(!test.check()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("DB connection failed!")
            }
        };
    }
```